# How to implement a radio button property in EF Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I want to implement a Male Female Radio Button Property. I generated the migration adding property, but I don't know how to get the values in Razor Pages.

My ApplicationUser.cs Class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeCode { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfJoining { get; set; }
    public string EmergencyNo { get; set; }
    public string AdharNo { get; set; }

    //Department dropdown and city and country thing
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string[] Genders = new[] { "Male", "Female", }; 

    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

I added Gender here. Then added Migration.

My RegisterModel class

```
//[AllowAnonymous]
//[Authorize(Roles = StaticDetails.AdminEndUser)]
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;

    ////comented the Iemailsender because its causing error.
    // private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    //// added by me for dependency injection;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    
    public RegisterModel(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
        // IEmailSender emailSender,
        ////added by me for constructor for the upper used dependency injection;
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        ApplicationDbContext db)
        
        
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        // _emailSender = emailSender;
        ////added by me for upper used constructor;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _db = db;

    }


    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        //added by me

        //[BindProperty]
        //public string Gender { get; set; }
        //public string[] Genders = new[] { "Male", "Female", "Unspecified" };

        //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        //[Column(TypeName = "Date")]
        //public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+)", ErrorMessage = "Only alphabets are allowed")]

        //public string FullName { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+)", ErrorMessage = "Only alphabets are allowed")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("(^.*$)", ErrorMessage = "Invalid EmployeCode")]
        public string EmployeCode { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }

        //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        //[Column(TypeName = "Date")]
        [Required]
        [BindProperty]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [BindProperty]
        public DateTime DateOfJoining { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Emergency No")]
        [MaxLength(10), MinLength(10)]
        public string EmergencyNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(12),MinLength(12)]
        public string AdharNo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        [MaxLength(10)/*, MinLength(10)*/]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [BindProperty]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string[] Genders = new[] { "Male", "Female", };
    }
    public class MobileUniqueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
            object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var _context = (ApplicationDbContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));
            var entity = _context.ApplicationUser.SingleOrDefault(e => e.PhoneNumber == value.ToString());

            if (entity != null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(/*GetErrorMessage(value.ToString())*/"Hey The MobileNo is Alrdy Present");
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public string GetErrorMessage(string mobile)
        {
            return $"Mobile {mobile} is already in use.";
        }

        //ValidationResult validphone = IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext);
    }
    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    }


        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            //var _context = (ApplicationDbContext)_db.ApplicationUser(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            //// var user = new Identityuser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };...I edited it because in Applicationuser class i am putting the name,address,city,postal code.
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = Input.Email,
                Email = Input.Email,
                FirstName = Input.FirstName,
                LastName = Input.LastName,
                EmployeCode = Input.EmployeCode,
                Designation = Input.Designation,
                //DateOfBirth= Convert.ToDateTime("DateOfBirth"),
                DateOfBirth = Input.DateOfBirth,
                DateOfJoining = Input.DateOfJoining,
                EmergencyNo = Input.EmergencyNo,
                AdharNo = Input.AdharNo,
                Address = Input.Address,
                City = Input.City,
                PostalCode = Input.PostalCode,
                PhoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber,
                Gender = Input.Gender,
                Genders = Input.Genders

                };

          
            ////after dependency injection we come to after post handler.and in below line they r creating the user.
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    ////added by me if this is successful we want chk if role exits in the detabase.
                    ////if admin user doesnot exits we want to creat it.
                    ////StaticDetails class SD created by me.
                    if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(StaticDetails.AdminEndUser))
                    {
                        await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(StaticDetails.AdminEndUser));
                    }

                    if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(StaticDetails.HrEndUser))
                    {
                        await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(StaticDetails.HrEndUser));
                    }

                    if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(StaticDetails.ItEndUser))
                    {
                        await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(StaticDetails.ItEndUser));
                    }
                    if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(StaticDetails.EmployeeEndUser))
                    {
                        await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(StaticDetails.EmployeeEndUser));
                    }

                    ////roles are created now have to assign it to a user.
                    ////adminuser for now.means when i will creat it will by default take adminuser.
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, StaticDetails.EmployeeEndUser);


                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    // await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    //   $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        
    }
}
```

My Register.cshtml class

```html
@page
@model RegisterModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

@*<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>*@

<h2 class="text-info pt-2 pb-3">Create a new account</h2>
<div class="row bg-white border">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.FirstName"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.LastName"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            @foreach (var gender in Model.ReturnUrl.Genders)
            {
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, gender) @gender<br />
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.EmployeCode"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.EmployeCode" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.EmployeCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Designation"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.Designation" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Designation" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.DateOfBirth"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.DateOfBirth" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.DateOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.DateOfJoining"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.DateOfJoining" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.DateOfJoining" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.EmergencyNo"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.EmergencyNo" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.EmergencyNo" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.AdharNo"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.AdharNo" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.AdharNo" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Address"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.Address" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Address" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.City"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.City" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.City" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.PostalCode"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.PostalCode" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.PostalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-info font-italic">.The Password must be at least 6 and at max 100 characters long,atleast one alpha numeric char and contain atleast one uppercase(A-Z).</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">Register </button>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>

</div>

@*<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>*@
@*<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
                <section>
                    <h4>Use another service to register.</h4>
                    <hr />
                    @{
                        if ((Model.ExternalLogins?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
                        {
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">this article</a>
                                    for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins)
                                        {
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                                        }
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        }
                    }
                </section>
            </div>
    </div>*@

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

How can I get that Genders list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  public class RegisterModel : PageModel
>  { 
>       ...
>      [BindProperty]
>      public InputModel Input { get; set; }
>  
>      public class InputModel
>      { 
>          ...
>          [Required]
>          [BindProperty]
>          public string Gender { get; set; }
>          public string[] Genders = new[] { "Male", "Female", };
>      } 
>      ...
>      }
> ```

From the above code, we can see you are using the InputModel to bind the property and the Genders/Gender, so, in the OnGetAsync method, we need to create the Input model instance, to prevent the Input model NullReferenceException. Code like this:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    Input = new InputModel();
    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
}
```

Then, when displaying the radio button in the view page, the code should be like this: access the Genders via the Input, and set the selected value using the Input.Gender.

```
@foreach (var gender in Model.Input.Genders)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Input.Gender, gender) @gender<br />
}
```

After that, the result is like this: we can get the selected gender via the `Input.Gender` property.

[image]